# XForms to HTML - looking for simple solution

Tags: php, html, xforms

I'm just looking for something that can transform XForms to traditional HTML Forms (or PHP as well). Let's say that I'm receiving form to generate in XForms, then my code (php) transforms it to traditional form and finally we have got a page with form. Well, I'm looking for that transforming box, could you recommend me something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My XForms implementation (XSLTForms) is doing this with an XSLT 1.0 transformation which can be applied at server-side (with PHP, for example) or, even, at client-side.

-Alain